# Convert "enquireScreen" js written for jsx to typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

Currently, I am trying to learn typescript through ionic react by creating simple webpages. I came across this interesting navigation bar but it is written in jsx. Hence, I want to write in tsx with the help of this website.

**Code in jsx**

```
import { enquireScreen } from 'enquire-js';

let isMobile;

enquireScreen((b) => {
  isMobile = b;
});

class Home extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    isMobile,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    enquireScreen((b) => {
      this.setState({
        isMobile: !!b,
      });
    });
  }
```

How do I write this in typescript? I have tried changing stuff like the declaration of the variable but could not get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried and what error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really have to do here is add types to your variables.

```
let isMobile: boolean;

enquireScreen((b: boolean) => {
  isMobile = b;
});

export class Home extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    isMobile,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    enquireScreen((b: boolean) => {
      this.setState({
        isMobile: !!b,
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Since the `enquire-js` doesn't come with type declarations and none are published to `@types`, you'll need to create a local declaration file and either write the declarations yourself, or declare the module with out any other declarations and it will suppress the `can't find module` errors.

Comment: Hi, supposedly my ionic react typescript started with this " const CreamyOreo: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = props => { return();}; " how do i fit the class into it ? Thanks.

Comment: You can't fit the class into this. The code you are showing there is using react functional components. While this code is typescript, it's not a Typescript specific paradigm. You can however convert the class to a functional component, you will just have to make use of the new hooks feature rather than lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

Create a new file name `enquire-js.d.ts` (I just put in on the root of the project)

```
declare module 'enquire-js' {
  var enquireJs: {
    enquireScreen: {
      cb: unknown,
      query?: string
    }
  }

  export = enquireJs
}
```

The warning goes away and compile without error.

(BTW, I am using enquire-js with next.js and antd)